# What is the process of converting the function of four variables into a function with two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, multilinear-algebra, multinomial-coefficients

When I have this function
$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_1x_3+x_2x_4$$

I convert it to a function with two variables

As an example $x_1=x_2=x,x_3=x_4=y$ I get $f(x,y)=2xy$

But I have many cases

1- $x_1=x_3=x,x_2=x_4=y$ I get $f(x,y)=x^2+x^2$

2-$x_1=x_4=x,x_3=x_4=y$ I get $f(x,y)=2xy$

...

I need to calculate all functions resulting from the  restriction

There will be a repetitive process of hypothesis for variables.

What is the process of converting the function of four variables into a function with two variables ?

Is there a mathematical basis for this process as a theory?

Thanks for the help

Comment: It might help to know the context of the question.  The conversion you showed is, essentially, imposing constraints on the domain of the original, 4-variable function.  So, it's all about what those constraints are.

Consider the 3-variable function: $f(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$ = x^{3}^2 - x_{1}^2 - x__{3}^4$.

Imposing different constraints on the three variables gives different mathematical objects.

Comment: What you’re describing is the restriction of $f$ to the plane $x_1=x_2$, $x_3=x_4$. On the other hand, you might also have chosen $x=x_1x_3$ and $y=x_2x_4$ and gotten $x+y$ instead. Be careful about the names of the functions, however. The function you get after your transformation is *not* the same as the original $f$ and using the same name can be a source of errors and confusion.

Comment: @amd I need to calculate all functions resulting from the  restriction see new update

Comment: There are many ways to “convert” this function to a function of two variables. You’re going to have to be more specific about what you’re trying to do. If you’re just equating pairs of variables, there are only 6 such pairings, which I don’t consider “many.”